# Data Science , Iris data set, target attribute, csv file

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, target

What does  "target" mean here? What happens in the line `y = iris.target`? How can I get the same result with a "normal" csv file, when I don't use the prepared iris data set?

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target
```

Comment: `target` is the column of values (in this case classes) that you try to predict. So if you read the CSV the column you try to predict would be your `target` -> `y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target are the labels array corresponding to each of the points. If working with a csv file, load into the `x` each of the `features` of the iris dataset (sepal and petal length and width) and load into `y` the column with the corresponding `labels`.

Hope it helps!